# Pass object or object attribute

Tags: java, oop

I have 2 Classes, Generator and Processor.  The former generates an ArrayList that is stored as a member attribute.  The latter processes that ArrayList.

My main Class instantiates one of each object and calls the appropriate methods.

What is better practise?

1. Pass the Generator object to the Processor object's process method
2. Pass the Generator object's ArrayList to the Processor object's process method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the `Processor` have any reason to care where the data comes from, or request that any more is generated? If not, just pass the data in as general a way as possible - e.g. `Iterable<T>`, `Collection<T>` or `List<T>`.

That way your code is less tightly coupled, and easier to test - heck you don't even have to *write* `Generator` before you test `Processor`, and if there are problems with your `Processor` unit tests, they're likely to be caused by a bug in `Processor`, not in `Generator`.

Comment: Thank you.  In that case should I make my Generator accessor return a List<T> rather than ArrayList<T>?  If so, should I declare declare the ArrayList as private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>?

Comment: @Laurence: Probably, yes to both. Just to check - presumably the member field is in this third class, and not in either Generator or Processor? I can't see why the Generator itself would need to hold on to the data it's generated.

Comment: The member field is in Generator.  It seemed to be logically owned by it to me.

Comment: @Laurence: Not given the name of the class. It should be generating data, not storing it. Its state should be whatever is required to generate the data, and then you should have a Generate method which generates the actual data and returns it. Of course I don't know your situation in detail, but that's what I'd expect given the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to pass the generator, rather than its attributes (exposed via a method, I assume).

Why ? I prefer to keep interfaces and coupling at a higher abstraction layer. By passing the object rather than the attributes I can change the generator at a later stage, and reduce the code sections I have to refactor.

Imagine - at some stage you may want to pass not just the list attribute, but perhaps something else alongside. By passing the higher level object you can limit your refactorings.

Of course this all depends on how widespread the usage of this object is. If you do decide to pass the attribute list, are you passing the list itself, or an *unmodifiable copy*.

Comment: I'm passing an unmodifiable copy.  I always tend to do this because I think it better preserves encapsulation.  Does that sound sensible?

Answer (score 0):

I would wonder why these aren't one object.  If Processor changes Generator's state, why isn't that method part of Generator?  Better encapsulation that way.  An interface with Generator's method would give you some nice flexibility, too.  A Generator could have a Processor interface, and you could pass in a concrete instance to change the implementation as needed.

Objects are state and behavior together.  Composition of Processor would let you adhere to that and still give you the flexibility to change what's done to the data.  Just a thought...

Comment: Processor manipulates the data and then saves it to a file. I kept Generator and Processor separate because I pass the List to Processor as an unmodifiableList, so Generator's state isn't actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

From design point of view your should create method

`List<YourType> getList()`

in Generator class then call it in main and pass the result to Processor.

Pay attention that in this case Generator and Processor are independent and do not "know" each other, so they can be modified independently. Moreover method returns List (not ArrayList), so the interface does not depend on list implementation too.

And the last point. The list is parametrized (`List<YourType>`) that makes it safer.

Comment: This is the implementation I went with in the first place.